# Apple URL Scheme for launching app from database information

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm quite frustrated with an issue I'm experiencing that Is coming with a lack of information. I'm unable to locate any information regarding my issue and I'm starting to believe It isn't possible what I want to do. Here is my issue and thank you for reading.

I would like for a button on my ViewController to open Apple Maps from Longitude and Latitude coordinates that are stored in my Sqlite database Tables. I have been able to successfully do this by adding a MapView. I want to reproduce this function and have the user be able to click "Get Directions" button and It will popup the Apple Maps app with the end address setup automatically. By using @"finishLat" and @"finishLng" I'm able to collect the database information. Is this possible when using the Apple URL Scheme?

This is a sample of what the Mapview does with the information. The only part I want from this is the @"finishLat" and @"finishLng". I will also need to use the "Run" feature as well to collect the correct address.

```
  [super viewDidLoad];
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
mapview = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width,  bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:mapview];

NSArray *result = [_runs objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *arr = [result objectAtIndex:0];
arr = [arr objectForKey:@"run"];

NSMutableArray *arrPlaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *arrDirvers = [arr objectForKey:@"drivers"];


for (int i =0; i < [arrDirvers count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *asdfg = [arrDirvers objectAtIndex:i];
        Place *startPt = [[Place alloc] init];
        Place *endPt = [[Place alloc] init];

        NSString *temp = [asdfg objectForKey:@"startLat"];
        startPt.latitude = [temp floatValue];
        temp = [asdfg objectForKey:@"startLng"];
        startPt.longitude = [temp floatValue];

        startPt.name = [asdfg objectForKey:@"name"];

        temp = [asdfg objectForKey:@"finishLat"];
        endPt.latitude = [temp floatValue];
        temp = [asdfg objectForKey:@"finishLng"];
        endPt.longitude = [temp floatValue];

        endPt.name = [asdfg objectForKey:@"name"];

        [arrPlaces addObject:startPt];
        [arrPlaces addObject:endPt];
```

This is what I have.

```
- (IBAction)GetDirections:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.apple.com/?q"]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `openURL:` you can create an instance of `MKMapItem` and use `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:`. You can supply the `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey` option to request directions from the users current location.

Alternatively, use `openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` to navigate between 2 known locations.

Answer (score 0):

To open in the Apple Maps app use:

```
- (IBAction)GetDirections:(id)sender 
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lattitude>,<longitude>"]];
}
```

If you want to open Apple Maps to a driving directions screen, you will need to use this url:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=<origin>&daddr=<destination>
```

You can also set one of these to be "Current%20Location" to use the user's current location.